# Class not found error when try to use XBase lib in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to use https://github.com/hisamu/php-xbase lib in my project.
I have copied XBase folder from repository to the my root and created index.php in my root.

When I try this code:

```
<?php

use XBase\Table;

$table = new Table(dirname(__FILE__) . 'data/test.dbf');

while ($record = $table->nextRecord()) {
    echo $record->my_column;
}

?>
```

I received this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'XBase\Table' not found in ...`

What is wrong?

Comment: Run `composer install` in xbase folder. Then include the generated autoload file: `require <xbase-folder-path>/vendor/autoload.php` in your php file.

Answer (score 2):

You are not requiring the file, that's why PHP can not find the class.

The example you see on GitHub, assumes you have installed and configured [composer](https://getcomposer.org) for your project.

To do this, download and configure composer, then run

```
composer require 'hisamu/php-xbase: *'
```

in root folder of your project. Then include `vendor/autoload.php` in your scripts. All installed classes using composer are now available.

Most frameworks do this for you, so you only use the class as mentioned. But when you are using a framework of yourself, or only plain PHP scripts, it's your responsibility to require `autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in the beginning of the `table.php` file:

```
include "Column.php";
include "Record.php";
```